# Accessing directive values in controller

Tags: angularjs

I realize there are similar questions to this already on SO but I can't find the solution to my problem.

I have the following directive which extracts a key and value for the input box that the cursor leaves (blur):

```
.directive('updateOneField', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: [],
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      element.bind('blur', function() {
        var key = attr.ngModel.split('.');
        key = key[key.length - 1];

        // Get the input value
        var value = element[0].value;


      });
    }
  };
});
```

This will potentially be used across multiple controllers so my question is how do I access the `key` and `value` values from any controller?

Comment: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/ I 've just found this blog thanks to your question and it really really explains **scope** in directive and also directives  very clearly . Take a look , thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the value of ngModel if I understand right, the most "angular-way" of doing this is to require ngModelController in your directive like so;

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.bind('blur', function() {
            var model = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
        });
    }
};
```

You can find more information about ngModelController [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass a controller scope variable to your directive and use this variable to access the value from the directive.

**Example**

```
<input type="text" update-one-field my-scope="myVariable" />
```

Here, `myVariable` is your controller's variable.

```
$scope.myVariable = {};
```

Now, update your directive like this,

```
.directive('updateOneField', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myScope: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {

            element.bind('blur', function() {
                var key = attr.ngModel.split('.');
                key = key[key.length - 1];

                // Get the input value
                var value = element[0].value;

                // Assign key and value to controller variable
                scope.myScope = {};
                scope.myScope.Key = key;
                scope.myScope.Value = value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now, you can access `key & value` from the controller just like,

```
// Code inside your controller
$scope.myVariable.Key; // Get key from the directive
$scope.myVariable.Value; // Get value from the directive
```

Hope this will help. If you have any doubt on this, please feel free to add comment.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in the directive declaration :

```
.directive('updateOneField', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    // her  -------------------------------> scope: [],
    scope : {},
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      element.bind('blur', function() {
        var key = attr.ngModel.split('.');
        key = key[key.length - 1];

        // Get the input value
        var value = element[0].value;


      });
    }
  };
});
```